# React: How to invoke a modal if components are unrelated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, components

I'm trying to get a modal to launch, however, with the current set-up, the components do not have a parent-child relationship and are completely unrelated. Is there any way to do this? I know the ideal is to have them in a parent-child set up, but this situation calls for them to be unrelated. I need the two buttons in App.js to be able to launch the modal, just like the buttons in Modal.js already can. Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import InputComponent from './components/input_component';
import Modal from './components/modal';


class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.modal.showFunction();
    this.refs.modal.hideFunction();
  }

  state = {
    fields: {},
  };

  onChange = updatedValue => {
    this.setState({
      fields: {
        ...this.state.fields,
        ...updatedValue,
      }
    });
};
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        <InputComponent onChange={fields => this.onChange(fields)}/>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.fields)}</p>
        <Modal container={this} ref="modal" />
        <button onClick={this.showFunction}>click to trigger show modal from App</button>
        <button onClick={this.hideFunction}>click to trigger hide modal from App</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Modal.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import '../styles/styles.css';

export default class Modal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    }
    this.showFunction = this.showFunction.bind(this);
    this.hideFunction = this.hideFunction.bind(this);
  }

  showFunction(){
    this.setState({
      show: true,
    })
  }

  hideFunction(){
    this.setState({
      show: false,
    })
  }

  render(){ 
    if(!this.state.show){
      return <button onClick={this.showFunction}>showModal</button>
    }
    return(
        <div className="modal-styles">
          <Modal show={this.state.show} container={this.props.container}>
            <h2>This will be the Modal</h2>
          </Modal>
          <button onClick={this.hideFunction}>hideModal</button>
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the two components are coming from two totally separate places, this could be a fringe case where it's most practical to just use the `window` variable. Note that the `/* GLOBAL window.etc */` syntax here isn't for ESLint, just for clarity.

**App.js**

```
/* GLOBAL window.__showModal */
/* GLOBAL window.__hideModal */

// class App...

  showFunction() {
    if (window.__showModal) {
      window.__showModal();
    } else {
      // Handle errors: Other component has not mounted
    }
  }

  hideFunction() {
    if (window.__hideModal) {
      window.__hideModal();
    } else {
      // Handle errors: Other component has not mounted
    }
  }
```

**Modal.js**

```
/* GLOBAL window.__showModal */
/* GLOBAL window.__hideModal */

// class Modal...

  componentDidMount() {
    window.__showModal = () => this.showFunction()
    window.__hideModal = () => this.hideFunction()
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    // Kill references to 'this'
    window.__showModal = undefined
    window.__hideModal = undefined
  }
```